# What animal does a Jorogumo summon?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, summoning

I'm running an AP that calls out an encounter with a [Jorogumo](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=1200). This appears to be a spellcasting monster, and its absolute top level spell is a 7th level Summon. So it seems important to playing this monster properly to use this spell. That means **I need to know exactly what it can summon**.

The spell is described as "7th summon animal (spiders only)". If I go look at [Summon Animal](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=316), a 7th level cast of it can summon up to a 9th level animal. None of the animals listed below it as 9th level options are in fact spiders.

If I ignore the listed animals and go look at the page for [Spiders](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterFamilies.aspx?ID=94), they've got a 6th level ([Giant Tarantula](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=387)) and an 11th level ([Goliath Spider](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=388)). Making them "elite" or "weak" only modifies the creature level by 1, so even that option would leave me with something of the wrong level.

I'm wondering first off if I'm missing something, or if this is a bug. Secondly, what the best creature to summon would be for this supposedly intelligent monster who made itself rather unfortunate spell slot learning choices.

---

My personal temptation would be to throw them out a weak Goliath Spider. Its 1 level too high, but I'm the DM, so I can hand-wave when I want to. They've been wrecking everything anyway.

Comment: I don't see the problem - heightening it increases the maximum level of creature it can summon, but presumably a 7th level summon animal can still summon a 6th Giant Tarantula, while being (I assume) harder to dispel etc due to being higher level. If Summon Animal only summons animals of the required level, wouldn't it be impossible to summon the Level 8 Bulette?

Comment: @Phoenices - Hmm. I didn't think about dispel (my table doesn't have that spell). That indeed could be a nit that makes "down summoning" like this worth doing. Perhaps that's what I was missing?

Comment: Are you just asking for a 9th level spider? You seem to understand what it can summon. There may not be one now, it's probably a bit of future/homebrew proofing.

Comment: @Jason_c_o - That, or failing that what I'm supposed to do (factoring in I don't want this boss to fold like a cheap lawn chair) for an appropriately high level summoned creature. That spell had to be made 7th level for a reason, right?

Comment: @T.E.D. you could also just rebuild those two spiders at level 9 or make your own, per the Build a Creature rules (https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=995). I've done this when I've wanted/needed to scale a creature multiple levels and it works really fairly well.

Comment: @ESCE - Not sure I have time to do that at this point, but I think that's a really good suggestion in general. I wonder how it compares to just making an elite-elite-elite Goliath Spider?

Comment: @T.E.D. adding elite (or weak) is basically a 1.5 level adjustment. Not all levels have a +/-2 jump, but it mostly works in a pinch. So a triple elite Goliath Spider would have an AC of 36, which moves the Goliath Spider from a Moderate AC for its level to a High AC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Any Common Spider up to 9th Level

> *Summon Animal*
>
> You conjure an animal to fight for you. You summon a common creature that has the animal trait and whose level is –1, such as those below. **Heightening the spell increases the maximum level of creature you can summon**.

As you've noted there aren't any 9th-level spiders in the list on Archives of Nethys, but they could summon any common spider of a lower level. They would be able to summon any future common spider given stats up to level 9.

> Because uncommon elements are available in certain circumstances, it often varies by locale, even within the same setting. For instance, a katana is uncommon in the *Core Rulebook* and in the Inner Sea region of Golarion, but in Asian fantasy–inspired Tian Xia, a katana would be common and some western weapons might be uncommon. Similarly, in an elven kingdom, uncommon elven weapons like the elven curve blade might be common.

Common as a rarity is a bit more negotiable based on the [context of the adventure](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=916), essentially allowing for some uncommon or even rare spiders to potentially count as common for the Jorogumo.

In particular, the uncommon 8th-level Giant Joro Spider included in the book Jorogumos are originally printed (*[Agents of Edgewatch: Assault on Hunting Lodge #7](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=1005)*) could be a good pick. This creature isn't currently on Archives of Nethys, but it may be added in some future update, and is available in the Foundry VTT Pathfinder 2e plugin.

The [elite adjustments](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=790) don't inherently increase rarity, so allowing them to summon an elite variant would be an option for summoning a 9th-level spider fitting their theme.

Comment: Ahhhh. That explains a lot! Rev 1 of this monster appears to have been in that book. So it looks like the original design idea was that it was summoning an elite Giant Joro Spider from its same book (a lvl 9 monster). When it got moved into Bestiary 3 without its spider, that kind of broke/nerfed that spell for it. I guess either nobody noticed the issue, or (less likely per Hanlon's Razor) they purposely nerfed it.

Comment: In fact, even if it was just summoning a non-elite Giant Joro Spider, as a lvl 8 animal that would have required the 7th rank (level) summon spell.